# Angular Data Table

Tags: angular, datatables

```
export class User {
    fname: string;
    lname: string;
    email: string;
    mobile: string;
    password: string;
    roles: Array<{
    name: string
  }>;
}
```

json Object

```
{
        "email": "multiUser@mail.com",
        "mobile": "9895276034",
        "fname": "test",
        "lname": "User",
        "password": "secret",
        "roles": [
            {
                "name": "accounts"
            },
            {
                "name": "ADMIN"
            }
```

My HTML

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="roles">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Roles</th>

  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data ">{‌{data.roles[0].name}}</td>

</ng-container>
```

Here there are two roles. The first role(ie: accounts i get it as above).
How do i get to the second role here(ie: "ADMIN" with the help of a loop.)

Please do help

Comment: use ngFor directive

Comment: but how and where @Chellappan

Answer (score 0):

I expect you want the `roles.name` in different rows here? `ngFor` directive is used to loop over a list in angular. Following is the snippet using `ngFor`.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="roles">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Roles</th>
    <tr *ngFor="let role of data.roles">
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data ">{‌{role.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: UserTableComponent.html:35 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (UserTableComponent.html:37)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:11061)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10458)
    at callViewAction (core.js:10699)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:10641)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10464)
    at callViewAction (core.js:10699)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:10662)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10459)
    at callViewAction (core.js:10699)

Comment: What is the name of your Json Object? You haven't mentioned the same. I assumed it is data.